# Clonar valores do textarea

Tags: javascript

Como clonar os valores do `textarea` de modo que ao digitar no `textarea 1` o `textarea 2` recebe esse valor e ao digitar no `textarea 2` o `textarea 1` recebe o valor?
Eu tentei `document.getElementById("ta").value = document.getElementById("ta2").value`, porém só funciona se digitar no 1 e não é possível digitar no 2

```js
function preview() {
    var valor = document.getElementById("ta").value
    var valor2 = document.getElementById("ta2").value
    var preview = document.getElementById("preview")
    var preview2 = document.getElementById("preview2")
    
    preview.innerHTML = valor
    preview2.innerHTML = valor2
};
```

```html
<textarea id="ta" oninput="preview()">Um</textarea>
<textarea id="ta2" oninput="preview()">Um</textarea>
<div id="preview"></div>
<div id="preview2"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

É necessário atribuir o novo valor ao atributo `value`.

**Exemplo:**

```js
const ta = document.querySelector("#ta")
const ta2 = document.querySelector("#ta2")

function preview(input) {
    /* Captura o valor do campo digitado e adiciona nos campos `ta` e `ta2` */
    ta.value = ta2.value = input.value
};
```

```html
<textarea id="ta" oninput="preview(this)">Um</textarea>
<textarea id="ta2" oninput="preview(this)">Um</textarea>
```